# How to contribute e4 part to Window > Show View > Other under Eclipse 4.4 (Luna)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, e4, eclipse-luna

I am struggling with contributing an e4 part (aka view) to the list of views accessible via *Window* > *Show View* > *Other*. Regardless of how I define my part descriptor in the `fragment.e4xmi`, the view doesn't show up there under **Eclipse 4.4 (aka Luna)**, neither under a specific category nor under *Other*. From Eclipse 4.5 on, everything works as expected.

Looking at the *View contribution using 4.x API* *Eclipse plug-in project* template, its part descriptor has two tags: `View` and `categoryTag:Sample Category`. On the *Default* page of the *Eclipse 4 Model Editor* there is also an explicit *Category* form field, also having a value of `Sample Category`.

I vaguely remember that the `categoryTag` is a legacy way of assigning categories to a view, but Eclipse 4.5 accepts both the `categoryTag` as well as the new, explicit *Category* attribute. And Eclipse 4.4 seems to accepts neither, so I suspect that I am doing something wrong or missing another magic `tag` to make this work with 4.4.

The *New & Noteworthy* documents for [4.4](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.4/eclipse-news-part3.php) and [4.5](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/platform_isv.php), respectively, don't indicate that there has been (aside from the `e4view` extension point) and changes to the way part descriptors are handled.

So I am wondering whether this is possible at all in Eclipse 4.4? (For 4.3, [it looks like it isn't](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/499424/).)